# Peculiar memory/printing issue C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void){
char dnachar [10]
int cytosine; //first int
int thymine;  //second int
int guanine;
int adenine;
printf("Enter DNA Sequence ");
scanf("%10s",dnachar);
printf("dna:%s\n", dnachar);

 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){

     char x = dnachar[i];
     if(x == 'c')
     cytosine++;
     if(x == 't')
     thymine++;
     if(dnachar[i] == 'g')
     guanine++;
     if(dnachar[i] == 'a')
     adenine++;
 }
printf("%d,%d,%d,%d",thymine, guanine, cytosine, adenine);
return 0;
}
```

Hi, I am new to C and I noticed that the program only prints the first two ints accurately - cytosine and thymine. The others show a random string of incoherent numbers. Why is that and how can I fix it?

edit: I changed i<20 to i<10, I don't know how I made that mistake.

Comment: Your code invokes *undefined behavior*. `char x = dnachar[i];` in a loop from 0..19 inclusive, how do you expect that to work when `char dnachar[10]` is the formal declaration? Your loop breaches memory access beyond your declared array size. Further, *none* of your declared `int` variables are determinate. They have no initial value formally defined. More undefined behavior. Your compiler should be spewing warnings about the latter issue, and if it isn't, turn up your warning levels and above all, treat them as errors because that's exactly what they are.

Comment: Hey WhozCraig, I always had my for loop at i<10, I don't know how I posted it as i<20. Good observation! I am not getting any errors though, I am using the 'Wall' and the cs50 sandbox if that helps .

Comment: Also, I thought undeclared variables are set to 0?

Comment: @user209835 Sometimes they are, yes. But not in this case. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/1597405/1679849

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Among the multitude of things wrong in this code

**Wrong format limiter**

Given:

```
char dnachar[10];
```

The code:

```
scanf("%10s",dnachar);
```

will read a string up to 10 characters long, *not* including the terminating null, which it will always place. Therefore, that `scanf` can write as many as eleven (11) chars in a space only declared to hold ten (10). The result of a ten character string read (or longer) will be *undefined behavior*.

Solution:

```
if (scanf("%9s", dnachar) != 1)
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
```

Note: if your sequences are really ten characters each, then `dnachar` should be declared as:

```
char dnachar[11]; // account for 10-chars + terminator
```

And the format string for `scanf` should be `%10s` accordingly.

---

**Indeterminate Counters**

All four of your counters are *indeterminate*. They have no specified initial value as *automatic* variables, and therefore operations expecting predictable results are unfounded. If they had static linkage (either globals or declared `static`) they would have default values of `0`, but that isn't what your code does.

Solution:

```
int cytosine = 0;
int thymine = 0;
int guanine = 0;
int adenine = 0;
```

---

**Incorrect Loop Limit**

Given:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
     char x = dnachar[i];
```

This assumes there are twenty characters in `dnachar` (which is impossible unless you've invoked undefined behavior from the item above). One you access `dnachar[10]` and beyond, more undefined behavior. Ideally you stop processing chars when there are no more, which is much easier with a pointer than an index.

Solution:

```
for (char *p = dnachar; *p; ++p)
{
    switch(*p)
    {
        case 'c':
            ++cytosine;
            break;
    
        case 't':
            ++thymine;
            break;
    
        case 'g':
            ++guanine;
            break;
    
        case 'a':
            ++adenine;
            break;
    
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```